# Reordering video tiles in Jitsi - working with DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, plugins, jitsi, video-conferencing

I want to add a function to Jitsi that allows alphabetic ordering of video tiles via booklet function.

I used [cketti's reorder.js](https://github.com/cketti/jitsi-hacks/blob/main/docs/reorder.js) as a basis since it works fine on my machine; however when I run my own script via console, the videos are not correctly shown (partly invisible) and audio breaks.
I am not very accostumed to JavaScript.

What am I doing wrong, what did I miss?
Alternatively: I do not really understand how to debug JS, how can I find out how I could reuse the reorder.js functions to correctly sort?

```
var container = $('#filmstripRemoteVideosContainer')[0];
var jChildren = $(container).children();
const numberOfVideos = jChildren.length;
var names = new Array();

//only applicable in tiles mode!
for(i=0; i<numberOfVideos; i++) {
  names[i] = new Array (2);
  names[i][0] = jChildren[i].getElementsByClassName("displayname")[0].innerHTML;
  names[i][1] = jChildren[i];
}

//sort Array
names.sort((a, b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0]))

//copy over to one-dimensional array
var newChildren = new Array();
for(i=0; i<numberOfVideos; i++) {
  newChildren[i] = names[i][1];
}

//convert to NodeList
var toNodeList = function(arr){
  var nodeList = document.createDocumentFragment();
  arr.forEach(function(item){
    nodeList.appendChild(item.cloneNode());
  });
  return nodeList.childNodes;
};

//Set new position
var remoteVideos = toNodeList(newChildren);
var videoTiles = $(remoteVideos).toArray()

// Set CSS 'order' properties to reflect current DOM order = display order
videoTiles.forEach(function(index) {
    $(this).css('order', -numberOfVideos + index);
});

//remove all videoTiles
for(i=0; i<numberOfVideos;i++){
  container.firstChild.remove()
}
// Add video tiles to DOM in sorted order (now the CSS 'order' property is used for the display order)
videoTiles.forEach(videoTile => container.appendChild(videoTile));
```

Edit: Here's the working code:

```js
    var container = $('#filmstripRemoteVideosContainer')[0];
    var jChildren = $(container).children();
    const numberOfVideos = jChildren.length;
    var names = new Array();
    
    //only applicable in tiles mode!
    for(i = 0; i < numberOfVideos; i++){
      names[i] = new Array (2);
      names[i][0] = jChildren[i].getElementsByClassName("displayname")[0].innerHTML;
      names[i][1] = jChildren[i];
    }
    
    //sort Array
    names.sort((a, b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0]))
    
    //reorder the tiles
    for(i=0;i<numberOfVideos; i++){
      $(names[i][1]).css('order', i);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're cloning the element nodes. Try reordering the existing ones by first removing them from the DOM, then adding them back in the desired order.

Comment: I finally managed to get it working. Figured, I don't actually need to remove the node to change the order, finally got the idea by checking your vip.js ;)